# Resizing DataGridView won't work correctly when RowCount = 1

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, resize

I wrote a code to resize (and adapt) a `DataGridView` to his content.
The code works correctly, except when `DataGridView.RowCount = 1`.

When there is only 1 row the Horizontal Scroll Bar appears and hide the row with data.

I run a lot of debug but wasn't able to understand where's the bug.

I solved adding an If (to add 2 pixels to Width when there is only a row) but isn't a solution and I would like to know where I'm wrong.
Here's my code:

```
Private Function DGV_Adapt(ByVal DGV_Name As String, ByVal RifCtrl_Name As String) As Boolean
    Dim adapted As Boolean
    Try
        Dim DGV As DataGridView = DirectCast(Me.Controls(DGV_Name), DataGridView)
        Dim RifCtrl As Control = Me.Controls(RifCtrl_Name)
        'Check screen size
        Dim ScreenDims As Rectangle = Screen.GetWorkingArea(New Point(0, 0))
        Dim MaxWidth As Integer = ScreenDims.Width - 15
        'Set MaxHeight by using reference control
        Dim MaxHeight As Integer = ScreenDims.Height - (RifCtrl.Location.Y + RifCtrl.Height + 40)

        Dim DGV_H As Integer = 0
        Dim DGV_W As Integer = 0
        'Set the DGV Width by using columns Width
        For Each C As DataGridViewColumn In DGV.Columns
            DGV_W += C.Width
        Next
        DGV.Width = DGV_W
        'Remove Horizontal ScrollBar by adding width
        Dim DGVHorizontalScroll As Control = DGV.Controls.OfType(Of HScrollBar).SingleOrDefault
        Do While DGVHorizontalScroll.Visible
            DGV.Width += 1
        Loop
        'Add 1 more pixel to width
        DGV.Width += 1
        'If is there a vertical ScrollBar then I get his width
        Dim VertSB_Width As Integer = 0
        Dim DGVVerticalScroll As Control = DGV.Controls.OfType(Of VScrollBar).SingleOrDefault
        If DGVVerticalScroll.Visible Then
            VertSB_Width = DGVVerticalScroll.Width
        End If
        'Set DGV Height by using Rows Height
        For Each R As DataGridViewRow In DGV.Rows
            DGV_H += R.Height
        Next
        'Add ColumnHeadersHeight to DGV Height
        DGV_H += DGV.ColumnHeadersHeight
        'If form size is enough to contain DGV I set his size
        'otherwise I set it to the max possible height
        If DGV_H <= MaxHeight Then
            DGV.Height = DGV_H
            'Try to remove Vertical ScrollBar
            Do While DGVVerticalScroll.Visible And DGV.Height <= MaxHeight
                DGV.Height += 1
            Loop
            adapted = Not DGVVerticalScroll.Visible
            'If VScroll was removed I need to resize Width
            If adapted AndAlso VertSB_Width > 0 Then
                DGV.Width -= (VertSB_Width) 
            End If
            'If DGV has onlu 1 row I need to add width
            '(I don't know why I need this!!!)
            If DGV.RowCount = 1 Then DGV.Width += 2
        Else
            DGV.Height = MaxHeight
            adapted = False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    Return adapted
End Function
```

Comment: Does your fix with the additional pixels not work at all or do you thinkt it is not a good coding style?

Comment: @AlexB. My fix works but It isn't a good coding and I would like to understand why the code doesn't work correctly even if DGV has only 1 row